# how to load and validate the video using paperclip-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

please help solve the problem.

using a paperclip I organized upload images. it works.

Now I would like to organize a video upload. I changed this model:
model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :video, presence: true

  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file   :video, 
                      :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, 
                      :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/  
  validates_attachment_file_name :video, :matches => [/3gp\Z/, /mp4\Z/, /flv\Z/]  

 validate :file_size_validation, :if => "video?"  

  def file_size_validation
    errors[:video] << "should be less than 2MB" if video.size.to_i > 30.megabytes
  end  
end
```

video controller:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)   

  if @video.save
    @video.update_attributes(user: current_user)

    flash[:success] = :video_created
    redirect_to @video
  else
    flash.now[:error] = :user_not_created
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

form:

```
<%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field  :title %>
    <%= f.file_field  :video %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

after attempting to upload the video I get the console the following error message:

```
Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-23 14:17:32 +0300
Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RF3w8PzZ9LZ4pdqRPqRvHMQ+nYDL4om0YHAMlzTm8tf3iFmVmKxXSYKap3C0ogEnOkifm9i01oXs/rTX9zmtPA==", "video"=>{"title"=>"tty", "video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f6624f10770 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150723-13428-u7s8i8.flv>, @original_filename="mmm.flv", @content_type="video/x-flv", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[video]\"; filename=\"mmm.flv\"\r\nContent-Type: video/x-flv\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Video"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/c4efd5020cb49b9d3257ffa0fbccc0ae20150723-13428-6gn39i.flv'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/c4efd5020cb49b9d3257ffa0fbccc0ae20150723-13428-1eailfd.flv[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/c4efd5020cb49b9d3257ffa0fbccc0ae20150723-13428-1eailfd.flv[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/c4efd5020cb49b9d3257ffa0fbccc0ae20150723-13428-khstwa.flv'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

on screen displays the following error message:

> Video Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

wherein imageMagik installed in my system:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

db:

```
  create_table "videos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "video_file_size"
    t.string   "video_updated_at"
    t.string   "video_file_name"
    t.string   "video_content_type"
  end
```

Comment: try adding this `, >= 3.4.1` to your gem paperclip in gem file  and then bundle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with `image` with `paperclip` and with `video` is different.Though the common point is that it will help you tu send the uploaded data to the server but you need to handle it with some processor.Just like you use `ImageMagick` for `images`,you should use `FFMPEG` to `encode/decode video`.
i will share the code which i usually use for video..but before that ,you must set up `ffmpeg` to handle all formats of video just like you did for `Imagemagick`.
**[here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)** is set up for ffmpeg and dont forget to provide path in environment file using `which ffmpeg`

you need **[ffmpeg-paperclip](https://github.com/owahab/paperclip-ffmpeg)** as well for coding/decoding videos.

```
video.rb
##using s3 
##convert the video into mp4 and also get screenshot of video at 5 sec
##add your own formats that you want 
has_attached_file :video,
  :styles => {
      :mp4video => { :geometry => '520x390', :format => 'mp4',
        :convert_options => { :output => { :vcodec => 'libx264',
          :vpre => 'ipod640', :b => '250k', :bt => '50k',
          :acodec => 'libfaac', :ab => '56k', :ac => 2 } } },
       :preview => { :geometry => '300x300>', :format => 'jpg', :time => 5 }
    },
    processors: [:ffmpeg],
    :storage => :s3,
    :size => { :in => 0..25.megabytes },
    :s3_permissions => :public_read,
    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

  validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
  validates_presence_of :video
```

once you have saved the video,you need to use some plugins to show the video player along with your video in `show` action.You can use **[Mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)**(my favorite).Download it,dump it in js/css files accordingly,Include it in application.js and application.css.

```
in your show.html.erb
##add video tag to show video

     <video autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="auto" style="width:100%;height:100%;" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%" poster="<%= @video.video.url(:preview)%>" >
      <source  src="<%= @video.video.url%>"  />
     <%if @video.video.expiring_url(:mp4video).present? %>
     <source type="video/mp4"  src="<%= @video.video.url(:mp4video)%>" />
      <%end%>
     </video>

    ##javascript to handle video player
    $('video').mediaelementplayer();
```

Comment: Oh, so there already is an implementation of video processing! Good to know. Seems like `ffmpeg-paperclip` is deprecated though, in favor of [`paperclip-av-transcoder`](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder).

Comment: While a great answer, it's a bit heavy handed. It may have been what the questioner actually wanted, but the question just stated needing to know how to upload video and get around the errors... Paperclip doesn't need a post processor (like ImageMagick for images) and it can simply handle the attachment/upload if desired (just don't run ImageMagick if the attachment content type matches anything other than an image).

Answer (score 2):

`paperclip`'s processor is designed for images, so it cannot handle videos. You're getting the error saying that ImageMagick did not recognize this file as an image. Fair enough, it's not an image!

Still, you could write a post-processor yourself, and [`paperclip`'s github page offers an example](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#post-processing) of the syntax that would be needed to call a custom processing class:

```
has_attached_file :scan, :styles => { :text => { :quality => :better } },
                         :processors => [:ocr]
```

This defines a variation of the attachment called `text` that is obtained by processing the uploaded file with a (hypothetical) `Paperclip::Ocr` class with options hash `{ :quality => :better }`

Choice of the exact conversion tool is up to you, but you do want to make sure that processing is done asynchronously, not inside the usual request-response cycle, you may want to use a background queue like Sidekiq, Que or Rails' (4.2+) ActiveJob.